# Find the splitting field of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

The extension $\mathbb{Z}_p \leq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is normal, as the splitting field of the polynomial $f(x)=x^{p^n}-x$ ($\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a perfect field therefore each polynomial is separable).

So, if $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, then $q(x)=Irr(a,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ can be splitted over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ (since all the roots are in $
\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$).

How can I find the splitting of $q(x)$ as an expression of powers of $a$??

We have that $q(x)=Irr(a, \mathbb{Z}_p)$, that means that $q(a)=0$.

Since $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ it stands that $a^{p^n}=a$.

Therefore, $q(a^{p^n})=0$.

How could I continue??

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the fact that if $f(a)=0$, where $f\in\mathbb F_p[x]$, then also $0=(f(a))^p=f(a^p)$? This implies that $q(x)=(x-a)(x-a^p)(x-a^{p^2})\cdots$

Comment: I got stuck right now... Why does it stand that $(f(a))^p=f(a^p)$ ??

Comment: And could you explain me also the implication??

Comment: sorry for the delay,  was away Eating. First question: because the coefficients are in $\mathbb F_p$, each of them having the property that $c^p=c$. Second question: if $a$ is a root of $f$, then $x-a$ divides $f(x)$.

Comment: I understand why it stands that $0=(f(a))^p=f(a^p)$!! 
$$$$ 
But I still haven't understood how this implies that $$q(x)=(x-a)(x-a^p)(x-a^{p^2}) \cdots $$ Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: $f(a)=0$, right? Thus $f(a^p)=0$. Also $f(a^{p^2})=0$. Etc. Don’t hesitate to e-mail me if you are still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;a\in\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ , then $\;\Bbb F_p(a)\subset\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ , and from here that $\;\Bbb F_p(a)\cong\Bbb F_{p^m}\;$ , with $\;m\mid n\;$ since $\;\Bbb F_{p^m}\;$ subfield of $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\iff m\mid n\;$ .

As you mentioned,  $\;a^{p^m}=a\;$ , but for this I'm not sure what else could "express with powers of $\;a\;$ the splitting field of $\;q(x)\;$" mean .